# Questions on if and else statements

Tags: java, if-statement

This is the question I saw on CodingBat:

Given 2 positive int values, return the larger value that is in the range 10..20 inclusive, or return 0 if neither is in that range.

And this is the code I have written:

```
public int max1020(int a, int b) {
  if ( a>=10 && a<=20 && b>=10 && b<=20 && a>b)
  return a;
  if (a>=10 && a<=20 && b>=10 && b<=20 && b>a)
  return b;
  if (a>=10 && a<=20 && b<=10 || b>=20)
  return a;
  if (a<=10 || a>=20 && b>=10 && b<=20)
  return b;

  else return 0;
}
```

I am fairly confident that it is correct but still then I click run, the websites says that: max1020(9, 21) → 0 BUT my code returns 9. Can someone help me to check through my codes what is wrong with it? :)

Comment: Why not simplify the code by just checking `a` is in the range first? Ditto with `b` then find the largest

Comment: `&&` has the same precendence as `||`, thus your if clauses read from left to right. You'll need to use parentheses around the "inner" clauses.

Comment: Indentation and braces are your friends.

Comment: @NicholasMa Btw I notice you're new to SO.  If Varun's answer helped you out, you should consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side of his answer, right below the up and down vote arrows.  Additionally, you can upvote an useful answer when you have enough rep for it.

Answer (score 3):

```
public int max1020(int a, int b) {
  if ( a>=10 && a<=20 && b>=10 && b<=20 && a>b)
  return a;
  if (a>=10 && a<=20 && b>=10 && b<=20 && b>a)
  return b;
  if ((a>=10 && a<=20) && (b<=10 || b>=20))
  return a;
  if ((a<=10 || a>=20) && (b>=10 && b<=20))
  return b;

  else return 0;
}
```

Adding brackets in 3rd and 4th line will fix the problem.

I suggest you change the `if` statements and use `else if`. It is just good coding practice to use `else if` statements instead of several `if` when possible.

Comment: Omgosh that's so careless of me! Thanks so much :)

Comment: What if `a` and `b` are in the range and `a=b`?

Comment: @Ed Heal 0 will be returned in that case.

Comment: That is for the OP to decide. Behavior is determined by what he actually wants to achieve. He can add another `if` statement to handle a case when `a=b` if he does not want `0` to be returned.

Comment: Surely the statement *Given 2 positive int values, return the larger value that is in the range 10..20 inclusive* tells us it should return a

Comment: I get your point but, well it says return the larger value. If both are equal, then there will not be a larger value. Ether way, I suggest the OP goes through the problem statement carefully. Details can be lost in translation as well :)

Comment: @VarunAgarwal OP copied the problem statement verbatim.  Some while ago, I made these exercises as well.  So I just logged in to check my old solution.  And noticed the site doesn't even check the `a=b` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is breaking in the third if condition, where you have || b>=20. 3rd and 4th conditions should be more specific like below:

```
   if (a>=10 && a<=20 && (b<=10 || b>=20))
       return a;
   if ((a<=10 || a>=20) && b>=10 && b<=20)
       return b;
```

Adding these parentheses will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

i would prefer to assign the checks to a variable to have a more "readable" code. but this depends on personal preferences.

```
public int max1020(int a, int b) {
    final boolean aInRange = a>=10 && a<=20;
    final boolean bInRange = b>=10 && b<=20;

    if (aInRange && bInRange) {
        if (a > b) {
            return a;
        } else if (a < b) {
            return b;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (aInRange) {
        return a;
    } else if (bInRange) {
        return b;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course Varun's answer is correct.  Additionally, I'd like to elaborate on some comments, and show an alternative approach to the problem that's much simpler and less likely to contain mistakes.

While reading the problem statement, you may notice that the method is to return a value if some conditions are met, or return `0` otherwise.  So you could initialize a result with the default value of `0`, change the result if the conditions are met, then return the result.  That would reduce the code to:

```
public int max1020(int a, int b) {
    int result = 0;

    if (a >= 10 && a <= 20) result = a;
    if (b >= 10 && b <= 20 && b > result) result = b;

    return result;
}
```

Can't make it much simpler, I'd think.  (But if you can, please comment, I love KISS! :) )

This solution produces a *slightly* different result, if both `a` and `b` are in range and `a=b`, it will return `a`.  The problem statement is not really clear if this should happen, as also shown by the comments to Varun's answer.  Coincidentally (or not) Codingbat doesn't check that condition.  The proposed solution on the site also returns `a` in this case.

If you think it should return `0` when `a=b`, it's quite easy to adjust,

```
public int max1020(int a, int b) {
    int result = 0;

    if (a != b) {
        if (a >= 10 && a <= 20) result = a;
        if (b >= 10 && b <= 20 && b > result) result = b;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Still pretty simple :)

To explain TJCrowder's comment about indentation: If you put the body of the `if` statement on the next line, you should use curly braces and indent the line.  Otherwise, it's far too easy to misread it, or make a mistake when you change the code.

```
// this can be error prone and harder to read,
// especially if you have multiple if statements,
// or add a statement to the body of the if statement in the future
// (shouldn't do this)
if (condition)
statement;

// Personally I think this is totally fine for a simple statement.
// But I know not everybody will agree
if (condition) statement;

// Usually, you'll see this formatting.
// Even without reading anything, the formatting makes it instantly clear 
//   which statements belong to the body of the if
if (condition) {
    statement;
}
```

Side note: the `else` statement in your code belongs *only* to the last `if`.  Your formatting could make that clear by not putting an empty line between those, e.g.

```
if (condition) statement;
else statement;

if (condition) {
    statement;
} else {
    statement;
}
```

In your code the `else` statement is actually obsolete, you could simply `return 0;` on the last line.

Varun's suggestion that you could use `else if`s is correct.  Theoretically, if the condition of the first `if` statement is true, using `else if` would make the code skip the tests for the other `if`s and be a little more efficient.  Additionally, it'd show that subsequent `if` statements are only reached if the previous `if` statements were false.

Practically however, in your code it doesn't really matter, because the method will finish and return a value if the condition is `true`, and subsequent `if` statements will never be reached anyway.